# How to use an AWS provided lambda layer in Terraform?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I am trying to run a python function on an AWS Lambda layer, I don't find any documentation on terraform to use an AWS provided lambda layer. How do I use AWS Provided lambda layer  `AWSLambda-Python27-SciPy1x` and runtime `Python 2.7`?

```
#----compute/lambda.tf----
data "archive_file" "lambda_zip" {
    type          = "zip"
    source_file   = "index.py"
    output_path   = "check_foo.zip"
}

resource "aws_lambda_function" "check_foo" {
  filename         = "check_foo.zip"
  function_name    = "checkFoo"
  role             = "${aws_iam_role.iam_for_lambda_tf.arn}"
  handler          = "index.handler"
  source_code_hash = "${data.archive_file.lambda_zip.output_base64sha256}"

  # i want to use lambda layer - AWSLambda-Python27-SciPy1x and run this function on it
  runtime          = "python2.7"
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You have to specify lambda layers as ARNs in terraform using [layers](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/lambda_function.html#layers) parameter:

> layers - (Optional) List of Lambda Layer Version **ARNs** (maximum of 5) to attach to your Lambda Function.

Using the following [syntax](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/lambda_function.html#lambda-layers) in terraform:

> layers = ["layer-arn"]

For example, the ARN for **AWSLambda-Python27-SciPy1x** in `us-east-1` region is:

> arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:668099181075:layer:AWSLambda-Python27-SciPy1x:24

If you not sure what is your ARN, you can create a dummy a Python 2.7 lambda function, add AWS layer `AWSLambda-Python27-SciPy1x` layer, and the console will give you its ARN.